# Grabbing masked URL in php from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-masking, domain-masking, domain-mask

How can I grab the masked URL in PHP from the htaccess? I have already tried `HTTP_HOST`, `REQUEST_URI` and `SERVER_NAME` but it always returns **.com** when I am trying to grab the masked url being **.nl** in this instance. `HTTP_REFERER` is not reliable and doesn't always have anything to refer from.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP always sees the host under which it was called, which in your case alsways will be domain.com. However, a solution would be to include a query parameter in the rewritten URL, like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1**?from=domain.nl** [P]
```

Depending on whether you may have a query-string in the incoming URL, you possibly will need two `RewriteCond`-`RewriteRule` Combinations, one starting the query-string with a question mark `?` and one appending to it with an ampersand `&` if the question mark is already there.

Comment: This is perfect. I wasn't sure how to add a querystring like that and that was the solution. Many thanks!